# Tag synonym for CSeries

Tags: support, tag-synonyms

I created the new [airbus-a220](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/airbus-a220) tag, can we have the older existing [cseries](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cseries) (x5) become a synonym of that?

Comment: I'm featuring it to get some more attention. If by the end of the week there is no dissenting opinion, you can proceed to suggest the the synonym and ping me in chat

Comment: @Federico I don't have enough score in the tag to suggest the synonym (only 2 people currently do,) but it's been around 2 weeks with no dissent. (FWIW, I agree it should be a synonym... it's the same plane, just renamed after the Airbus acquisition.)

Comment: @reirab time is not what I am looking at. when I made this post featured it had only 14 views, not really a community consensus.

Comment: @Federico Oops, I was looking at the timestamp on the question instead of your comment. I thought it had been a couple of weeks since you posted the bit about suggesting the synonym if there wasn't any dissent by the end of the week. My bad. Anyway, agreed that it would be good to have more input. Thanks for featuring.

Comment: synonym created and merged

Comment: @Federico - Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds reasonable. It’s the same project.